# restricting a number to specific decimal places

Tags: python-3.x

I want to restrict a number to certain decimal places. For e.g: 0.973451 to  4 decimal places would be 0.9374.Note: The numbers I want to restrict  are in numpy array - type Float64

I'm performing operations on numbers that have many digits after decimal places.
When I perform mathematical operations like multiplication or exponential, it shows "overflow error".

Comment: overflow arrow is for BIG numbers ... you are throwing away tiny fractions ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [round](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.round_.html) method in numpy.

```
numpy.round_(a, decimals=0, out=None)
```